# Multiply two Series with MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiply two `Series`, both with `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(0, 100, 1000),(0, 100, 1001),(0, 100, 1002), (1, 101, 1001)]
index_3levels=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples,names=["l1","l2","l3"])
tuples = [(0, 100), (1, 101)]
index_2levels=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples,names=["l1","l2"])
data_3levels = pd.Series(1, index=index_3levels)
data_2levels = pd.Series([2,3], index=index_2levels)
print data_3levels  
l1  l2   l3  
0   100  1000    1
         1001    1
         1002    1
1   101  1001    1
dtype: int64
print data_2levels
l1  l2 
0   100    2
1   101    3
dtype: int64
```

The problem is that I cannot reindex the `Series` from 2 to 3 levels:

```
data_2levels.reindex(data_3levels.index, level=["l1","l2"])
Exception: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
```

I found this workaround:

```
for l1 in [0,1]:
    data_3levels[l1] *= data_2levels[l1].reindex(data_3levels[l1].index, level="l2")
print data_3levels
l1  l2   l3  
0   100  1000    2
         1001    2
         1002    2
1   101  1001    3
dtype: int64
```

But I think there should be a method to perform this operation in just 1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `reset_index` removes the last level, so they are the same when you multiply

```
In [25]: x = data_3levels.reset_index(level=2,drop=True)*data_2levels
```

Since you want the original index (and the shape hasn't changed), this works.

```
In [26]: x.index=data_3levels.index

In [27]: x
Out[27]: 
l1  l2   l3  
0   100  1000    2
         1001    2
         1002    2
1   101  1001    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested this on my actual dataset (few million samples), the reset index is quick, but the multiply is very slow, I guess because matching the indices is slow. Is there a more efficient option?

Comment: sure just multiply the arrays themselves and set the index after; but you must make sure that the data is the same size. what is your goal here?

Comment: Arrays are not the same size, exactly like in this example. First array has 3 levels, second has just the first 2, I want to multiply them on the matching indices.

Comment: @Jeff: This solution only works if the index is properly sorted *before* you drop one of the levels. Otherwise, the new index will be sorted differently to the old one and the result will be incorrect! See [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround to this until a 'nice' solution comes about via various enhancement requests.

You can simply:

- `unstack` the problematic index level(s) away
- do the multiplication
- `stack` the problematic index level(s) back.

Like this:

```
In [92]: data_3levels.unstack('l3').mul(data_2levels, axis=0).stack()
Out[92]: 
l1  l2   l3  
0   100  1000    2
         1001    2
         1002    2
1   101  1001    3
dtype: float64
```