# Binary operation broadcasting across multiindex

Tags: pandas

can anyone explain why broadcasting across a multiindexed series doesn't work? Might it be a bug in pandas (0.12.0)?

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                  'country':['A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],
                  'prod':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
                  'val':[10,20,15,25,20,30,25,35]})
x = x.set_index(['year','country','prod']).squeeze()

y = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,1,2,2],'prod':[1,2,1,2],
                  'mul':[10,0.1,20,0.2]})
y = y.set_index(['year','prod']).squeeze()
```

From the description of matching/broadcasting behavior from the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) I would expect to be able to multiply `x` and `y` and have the values of `y` broadcast across each `country`, giving:

```
>>> x.mul(y, level=['year','prod'])
    year  country  prod
1     A        1       100.0
               2       2.0
      B        1       150.0
               2       2.5
2     A        1       400.0
               2       6.0
      B        1       500.0
               2       7.0
```

But instead, I get:

```
Exception: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
```

*(Note that this is a variation on the theme of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470077/multiply-two-series-with-multiindex-in-pandas).)*

Comment: Additionally, I can't really work out why this doesn't work: `x.groupby(level='country').transform(pd.Series.mul,y)`

Comment: This is essentially unimplemented ATM, as its pretty tricky. See the references question for a way to do it (swap levels first, then reset).

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Can you shed any light on why the join is reported as being ambiguous? It's a rather opaque error given the circumstances! (p.s. maybe it's finally time to do my first fork of the source code!)

Comment: I don't think it's ambiguous more that it just needs to be implemented (their might be some ambiguity if the levels could match in multiple ways; prob have to assume that the order of the levels is the join order). this is pretty analogous to doing a straight frame-frame join I think so could be straightforward.

Comment: another way to approach this is to reset the index on both frames, then join them, set the index and multiply

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes, I've solved it this way in the past. I don't think either of these solutions is clear to the reader of the code. Yet I find myself wanting to do this sort of thing all the time, so maybe I should have a look at the binary operators in the source code and see what I can do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42538/discussion-between-londonrob-and-jeff)

Comment: that would be great lmk if u need help. open an issue with an example (this one), which becomes a test case and create the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed by me and @jreback in [the issue opened to deal with this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5645#issuecomment-118881042), a nice workaround to the problem involves doing the following:

1. Move the non-matching index level(s) to columns using `unstack`
2. Perform the multiplication/division
3. Put the non-matching index level(s) back using `stack`
4. Make sure the index levels are in the same order as they were before.

Here's how it works:

```
In [112]: x.unstack('country').mul(y, axis=0).stack('country').reorder_levels(x.index.names)
Out[112]: 
year  country  prod
1     A        1       100.0
      B        1       150.0
      A        2         2.0
      B        2         2.5
2     A        1       400.0
      B        1       500.0
      A        2         6.0
      B        2         7.0
dtype: float64
```

I think that's rather good, and should be pretty efficient.