# pandas subtracting two grouped dataframes of different size

Tags: python, pandas

i have two dataframes:

my stock solutions (df1):

```
pH   salt_conc
5.5  0            23596.0
     200          19167.0
     400          17052.5
6.0  0            37008.5
     200          27652.0
     400          30385.5
6.5  0            43752.5
     200          41146.0
     400          39965.0
```

and my measurements after i did something (df2):

```
pH   salt_conc  id
5.5  0          8     20953.0
                11    24858.0
     200        3     20022.5
     400        13    17691.0
                20    18774.0
6.0  0          14    38639.0
     200        1     37223.5
                2     36597.0
                7     37039.0
                10    37088.5
                15    35968.5
                16    36344.5
                17    34894.0
                18    36388.5
     400        9     33386.0
6.5  0          4     41401.5
                12    44933.5
     200        5     43074.5
     400        6     42210.5
                19    41332.5
```

I would like to normalize each measurement in the second dataframe (df2) with its corresponding stock solution from which i took the sample.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Look at the `level` argument on the `.sub` method of df2. You can broadcast across

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with the help of this post:
[SO: Binary operation broadcasting across multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383972/binary-operation-broadcasting-across-multiindex)

I had to reset the index of both grouped dataframes and set it again.

```
df_initial = df_initial.reset_index().set_index(['pH','salt_conc'])
df_second = df_second.reset_index().set_index(['pH','salt_conc'])
```

No i can do any calculation i want to do.